# What does the --filename option of mtr actually do?

Tags: mtr

I was looking for a tool to display the continuous ping loss to multiple hosts, and I looked at [mtr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)) as it already has the display I was thinking about. I saw that it has this option which sounded promising:

```
  -F FILENAME, --filename FILENAME
          Reads the list of hostnames from the specified file.
```

Unfortunately, I cannot understand what `mtr` does with this **list** of hostnames. It seems to only pick up the first one from the list and report on it.

How is the "list of hostnames" used by mtr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 years too late, but I figured it out.

https://github.com/traviscross/mtr/pull/169/commits/c419873aceb7c416cea91724f3e282befc56ecae

From the commit log:

> [...] Also, multiple host names will now work in all non-interactive modes
> (i.e. report, txt, json, xml, raw, csv) instead of just CSV mode.

In interactive mode it latches onto the 1st host. I was hoping I could just get a sidescrolling multi-host `ping` ... no dice